# How to grep or sed with two patterns and print result in one line

Tags: bash

My bash variable $line contains output of other command. Ip and username could be in different places inside one line :

```
10.20.0.11 01User3645 123213123213 http://amazon.com
af 10.20.0.12 http://amazon.com 02User4536
01User3645 123213123213 10.20.0.11 http://amazon.com
af 02User4536 http://amazon.com 10.20.0.12
01User0011 123213123213 http://amazon.com 10.20.0.11
```

I'm trying to sed or grep this variable with two patterns to get only ip address and username:

```
10.20.0.11 01User3645
10.20.0.12 02User4536
10.20.0.11 01User3645
10.20.0.12 02User4536
10.20.0.11 01User0011
```

With commands bellow it was possible to print desired result but with separated lines:

```
echo "$line" | grep -E -o '10\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+User[0-9]+'
```

Output:

```
10.20.0.11
01User3645
10.20.0.12
02User4536
10.20.0.11
01User3645
```

The question here is how to combine output of ip-address and username in one line for each line in variable?
Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `grep -E -o '10\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ +[0-9]+User[0-9]+'`

Comment: Are you just trying to print the first two columns? colrm or awk

Comment: @anubhava ip and username could be in different places inside string, not exactly first and second

Comment: @Andy: Change your example to a more appropriate one.

Comment: @Cyrus I did, my bad

Comment: @stark No exactly. I' ve changed text and example for better understanding

Comment: @Cyrus Thank you kindly!) Not enough reputation yet to cast a vote, but it helped a lot)

Comment: @Cyrus Also one more question: i put grep output from remote file to $line variable that you helped me with. Could there be some troubles if file large - big log file for example.

Comment: Pipe your output into `| paste - -` to collect the two results into one line. That uses a tab separator; use `| paste -d ' ' - -` for a space separator.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` solution for this task:

```sh
awk '
match($0, /10\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/) {
   printf "%s ", substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
}
match($0, /[0-9]+User[0-9]+/) {
   print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
}' <<< "$line"

10.20.0.11 01User3645
10.20.0.12 02User4536
10.20.0.11 01User3645
10.20.0.12 02User4536
10.20.0.11 01User0011
```